# I need help with partial derivative question

Tags: partial-derivative

[image]

Can anybody please help me out, i can't figure out how to work this one

Comment: See [How to find a partial derivative of an implicitly defined function at a point](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/359957); many other examples are found by searching for *implicit partial derivative*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$3y=z^3+3xz$$
$$0=3z^2\frac{\delta z}{\delta x}+3z+3x\frac{\delta z}{\delta x}$$
$$0=z^2\frac{\delta z}{\delta x}+z+x\frac{\delta z}{\delta x}$$
$$z=-(z^2+x)\frac{\delta z}{\delta x}$$

from
$$0=z^2\frac{\delta z}{\delta x}+z+x\frac{\delta z}{\delta x}$$
$$0=2z(\frac{\delta z}{\delta x})^2+z^2\frac{\delta^2 z}{\delta x^2}+\frac{\delta z}{\delta x}+\frac{\delta z}{\delta x}+x\frac{\delta^2 z}{\delta x^2}$$
$$\frac{\delta^2 z}{\delta x^2}(z^2+x)=-2(z(\frac{\delta z}{\delta x})^2+\frac{\delta z}{\delta x})$$
taking in account that $$\frac{\delta z}{\delta x}=\frac{-z}{z^2+x}$$ follow that
$$\frac{\delta^2 z}{\delta x^2}=\frac{2xz}{(z^2+x)^3}$$

Comment: Thanks alot adi...if possible can you please elaborate a little, i am confused about the last part.    0=z2δzδx+z+xδzδx
0=2z(δzδx)2+z2δ2zδx2+z+δzδx+xδ2zδx2

Comment: @AliBaloch Take the derivatives of both sides with respect to $x$. (Product rule + implicit differentiation)

Comment: @Adi Dani if possible could you please explain how to get to the final answer from third last & second last line :p